# How to programme progress when max value is not known before a method is called?

Tags: java

On the remote server, there is a 5-digit numbers of particles. As they are being downloaded, the progress has to be updated. The number of particles is not known before the 3rd party downloader starts. So my methods look like this

```
//Method calling progress counter
@Override
public void onUpdated(Object fetcher, int particlesRemaining) {
    //particlesRemaining is int like 10240
    int progress = (int) countProgress(particlesRemaining);
    setProgress(progress);
}

//method counting progress
public static double countProgress(int particlesRemaining) {
    //???how to set maxValue???
    double temp = 100 / maxValue * (maxValue - particlesRemaining);
    return temp;
}
```

A parameter `particlesRemaining` is not known before I first time call `countProgress`. The first-time value is always the Max value and all subsequent values are smaller than the first one.

So how shall I set `maxValue` once when I don't know it's value before `countProgress` has been called **for the first time**? After setting is first time as the max value, I have to lock it from changing.

Comment: Are you talking about initialization? Do you want max value to be anything as long as its larger than anything else?

Comment: Only set `maxValus` when you first recieve a valid value for `particlesRemaining`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't the first 'particlesRemaining' be the max value?

then you could do:

```
//in class variables
int maxValue=0;

//method counting progress
public static double countProgress(int particlesRemaining) {

    //???how to set maxValue???
    if(maxValue<particlesRemaining) {
        maxValue=particlesRemaining;}
        double temp = 100 / maxValue * (maxValue - particlesRemaining);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Don't forget if you use it several times you need reset `maxValue` before use

Comment: Yes, first value is the max value. I will try this asap.

Comment: Don't forget if you use it several times you need reset `maxValue` before use

Answer (score 1):

Add field.

```
int maxValue;
```

Change your onUpdated

```
public void onUpdated(Object fetcher, int particlesRemaining) {
    if(maxValue =n null) {
          maxValue = particlesRemaining;
          setProgress(0);
    } else{
         setProgress(100 / maxValue * (maxValue - particlesRemaining));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

`maxValue = INTEGER.MAX_VALUE` will give you the biggest number Java can process

Comment: `countProgress()` would then typically return numbers close to 100% with `maxValue` set this way.

Comment: @davida.:  `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is, in fact, an `int`.